# Read binary data through MATLAB

Tags: usrp, rtl-sdr, android-gnss

I have record the GPSL1 signal in the .bin format using USRP 2900
Parameters are:

Frequency = 1575.42M
I/Q rate = 4M
Gain = 25dB............... Now i want to extract tracking data in .mat form and in .dat form can you help me

fid = fopen('test01.bin', 'rb');  % Open .bin file in binary mode for reading
data = fread(fid, 'int16');  % Read the data as unsigned 8-bit integers
fclose(fid);  % Close the file

% Perform parsing operations to extract tracking data and timestamp
% Save the tracking data in a .dat file

fid = fopen('tracking_data.dat', 'wb');  % Open .dat file in binary mode for writing
fwrite(fid, data, 'int16');  % Write the 'data' array to the .dat file
fclose(fid);  % Close the file

% Perform parsing operations to extract tracking data and timestamp

latitudeData = data(1:3:end);  % Adjust the indexing based on the structure of the data
longitudeData = data(2:3:end);  % Adjust the indexing based on the structure of the data
timestampData = data(3:3:end);  % Adjust the indexing based on the structure of the data

% Save the tracking data in a .mat file
trackingData = struct('latitude', latitudeData, 'longitude', longitudeData, 'timestamp', timestampData);
save('tracking_data.mat', 'trackingData', '-v7.3');